# Python Selenium test succeeds when run individually but gives Chromedriver error when run as part of defaultTestLoader

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a Selenium Test in Python, and when I run the test file it works, but when I try to run a testLoader with that test it gives an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90

Current browser version is 115.0.5790.102 with binary path C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

My selenium is updated to the latest version, and Chrome starts and the test runs correctly when I click run on the test file in Pycharm, but not when running it as part of defaultTestLoader (with one or multiple tests, if multiple tests then all tests fail the same way). This code was working until recently, when I had to change the code and update selenium because of the Chromedriver location changes.

testLoader code:

```
test_suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(start_dir='./tests', pattern='ExampleTest.py')
combo_suite = unittest.TestSuite(test_suite)

runner.run(combo_suite)
```

Chrome start code:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    chrome_options.binary_location= "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
```

If I download the chromedriver file and link to it in the code then everything works both times.

```
service = Service(executable_path="/drivers/chromedriver.exe")
cls.driver = webdriver.chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the `@classmethod` as follows:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    driver=cls.driver
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    chrome_options.binary_location= "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Thing is, this setUpClass isn't in the file itself, it's in a separate file that the test inherits from, so this doesn't work.
Adding it to the test file and removing the code from the base class got the same result as the post, though.